# I can't earn correct result when I use IsNan function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I can't earn correct result when I use IsNan function in javascript
WHEN I INPUT NUBER (EX 2342, 1111 ...) IsNan function result is true.
I think inNan function recognize letter not a number.
How can I fixed it?

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>


<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value='/resources/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js'/>"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#insertbtn").on("click",function(){
            var updateno =$("#no").val().replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
           alert(updateno);

            if(!updateno.isNan){
                alert("YOU HAVE TO INPUT NUMBER VALUE");
            }else if(updateno.length<5){
                alert("YOU HAVE TO INPUT 5 CHARACTOR ");
            }else {
                $("#insertform").submit();
            }
        });
    });


</script>
<body>
<div class="all">

    <%@ include file="layout/header.jsp" %>

<div>

    <%@ include file="layout/menu.jsp" %>


  <form method="POST" action="memberinsert" id="insertform" >

 <div class="main">
   <c:if test="${not empty no}" >
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>NAME</th>
    <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name"></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <th>EPLOYEENUMBER</th>
    <td><input type="text" name="no" id="no"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>パスワード</th>
    <td><input type="text" name="password" id="password" ></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td colspan="2" style="background: white;border-bottom: dotted red;" align="right">
        <input type="button" id="insertbtn" value="SUBMIT"   class="btn btn-default" >
     <!--    <input type="button" id="canclebtn" onclick="location.href='memberlist'"> -->
   </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</c:if>
 <c:if test="${empty no}" >
  IF YOU WANT TO USE THIS SERVICE YOU HAVE TO NEED LOGIN
   </c:if>
 </div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: `number.isNan` => `isNaN(number)`

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
if(isNaN(updateno)){
                alert("YOU HAVE TO INPUT NUMBER VALUE");
}
```

Comment: @prepare123,  Happy Coding :P

Comment: I can't recognized that isNan is miss typinged!   I try to follow that Sunny's advice and succeed !  javascript support var type and maybe I think isNaN can recognized Number when that's parameter value is 'Number' . of course your advice is correct too!

Answer (score 0):

You are using it in a wrong way. Notice that `NaN` has two big N's. `Number.isNaN` is a [function on the `Number` object prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN). The correct way to invoke it is `isNaN(something)`.

Your `updateno` variable is a string. So you cant call `isNaN` on it.

What I think you are trying to do is something like this:

```
// Attempt to convert the string into a number
var updateno = parseInt($("#no").val().replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ""));

if (!isNaN(updateno)) {
  // it parsed as a number
} else {
  // it wasn't parseable to a number, parseInt returned `NaN`
}
```

Comment: your comment is very useful to me thankyou! I can't recognized that isNan is miss typinged!    I try to that Sunny is advice and succeed !